# XML parsing in iOS, unable to get the values

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

I have been trying to do XML parsing in iOS. But I was not able to parse it unfortunately.

Can you help me with this. I was using a SAX parser using NSXML.

The data is

```
<category>
<cat id="info" name="id1" value="val1" />
<cat id="info" name="id2" value="val2" />
</category>
```

How do i get the values using SAX parser? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

**Answer**-

(To get the attributes)
I used it this way (attributedict is the NSDictionary object in didStartElement method)

```
NSString *attr = [attributeDict valueForKey:@"name"];
if([attr isEqualToString:@"id1"])
{
NSLog("%@", [attributeDict valueForKey:@"value"]);
}
```

Comment: "I was using a SAX parser". Err, maybe you should tell us which SAX parser and what problems you were having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to init an NSXML instance with Data then use the parse method. You need to set up a NSXMLParserDelegate protocol, then using the following methods, you'll be able to retrieve information :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *) namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
```

You should read the apple documentation about it :

[NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[NSXMLParserDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

You'll find Apple examples in the links.

Comment: Thanks, the documentation helped :)